# Did Luther add a word to Romans 3?

Tags: martin-luther, sola-fide, romans

There are many who have pointed out that Luther added the word, "alone" to Romans 3:28 (you can read one such example in [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/can-someone-help-me-cite-luthers-explanation-of-faith-alone-to-catholics)) so that the Luther Bible reads:

> for we reckon a man to be justified by faith alone without deeds of law

where the Greek reads:

> for we reckon a man to be justified by faith without deeds of law

Is this true?

Comment: Related to [this BH question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5593/3332)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes he added it, no it is not the atrocity that it necessarily implies.

Part of Luther's defense of the translation is that inclusion of the word "alone" is more grammatically correct than its exclusion. While I'm not an expert in German, I do speak enough of it to know that he does have a point.

His problem, though, is in the interpretation of the verse. If we're being true to the original Greek the passage is better understood, "of the set `{faith, works of the law}` man is only reconciled by faith."

Comment: ...and that is quite a problem, because it puts him directly at odds with both Christ and James, who teach clearly and unambiguously that **obedience to the Gospel** (which means works, but not "of the law" (of Moses), which is what Paul was talking about here) are also necessary.  Putting a "sola" in there destroys the idea of the well-defined set that Paul mentioned, and builds an entire theology on a false and dangerous premise.

Comment: @MasonWheeler then Paul created a false set, no? Why waste time (and be so misleading) saying: "Well, between these two items 'A' and 'B' in the set, it would be only item 'A' that is sufficient and necessary" when what he really meant was "Item 'A' isn't sufficient. You must add a third item, 'C.'" We can discuss what the biblical definition of "faith" is and what it includes, but it is evident in Romans that Luther didn't change anything by adding the word. Or so says me, a crazy Baptist. :)

Comment: @SanJacinto: Because the point of the sermon in question was not to specify what is necessary for salvation, but what **is not**: obedience to the Law of Moses. The Law of Moses was supposed to produce faith in adherents and turn their mind to the Savior (see Galatians 3,) but it was perverted by the Rabbis to the point where they ended up essentially worshiping the Law itself. Paul's point here is that it is the faith produced by the observation of the Law that can lead to salvation; the actual works of the Law, divorced from faith, are irrelevant. Luther loses that point, which is dangerous.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I think it is a non sequitur to say that because Paul is stating that the law is powerless to yield salvation means that he believed that our active obedience is a condition of salvation. I will let you have the last word, but I want to ask one question: in Romans 3:31, Paul says that by this faith, we uphold the law. If 'works' are a part of this faith by union (as opposed to effect), how does this uphold the law? Is this better asked as its own question, directed toward Roman Catholics (I assume that you are Roman Catholic)?

Comment: @MasonWheeler & SanJacinto

This looks amusingly like a discussion. Perhaps a second question is in order?

Comment: @MasonWheeler obedience to the Gospel is a *fruit* of salvation, not a precursor. Works are fruit, and as such are "necessary", but only insomuch as they are evidence of what God already did, what already happened spiritually, by Grace, not by works... that no one may boast.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch I agree with you. Paul ends the chp. 2 stating that it is not external behavior that counts, but internal change that manifests an external change; mentioning that God gave circumcision as an external sign and seal to Abraham in response to Abraham's faith in His promises and reinforcing a concept that was also present in OT -> “Circumcision of the heart” (Deut. 30:6; Jer. 4:4). In the beginning of cp.3 then we see that we keep God's commandments (John 14:15, 15:10, etc.) NOT to become or to be righteous, but because we love God and have already been saved.

Comment: All have sinned and fallen short; therefore, they all share the same need for God's justice. Fortunately, justification was made available by a gift of God's grace (end of chp. 3)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, clearly and obviously, Luther added the word "alone" to his translation. But that's not the real question to ask. If you'll permit a small digression, the real question is **why**.  It is clear that his reason is to make the meaning of the greek in the *receptor* language (german).  In other words, the greek carries with it the nuance of 'alone' in the greek itself without the word, 'alone.' (“⸀λογιζόμεθα ⸁γὰρ δικαιοῦσθαι ⸂πίστει ἄνθρωπον⸃ χωρὶς ἔργων νόμου.” (Romans 3:28 NA28-T)) So, for the sake of bringing this clearly over into his *target* language he adds the word alone.  Here's an excerpt from Luther's open letter on translating

"You tell me, besides, that the papists are making a tremendous fuss, because the word *sola* is not in Paul's text, and this addition of mine to the words of God is not to be tolerated...But because I knew—and still see with my own eyes—that none of them knows how to translate, or to speak German, I spared them and myself that trouble.."

To word it slightly differently, the issue to Luther was a *translation* issue far more than a doctrinal issue in his translation of Romans 3:28.  He was simply striving to bring the precision of the greek into the German. Paul is setting up an exclusive statement. "We conclude that a person is declared righteous" (λογιζόμεθα ⸁γὰρ δικαιοῦσθαι). But then Paul front-shifts the instrumental dative for emphasis (prolepsis) out of its normal position. So we would add weight and emphasis to this by saying something like "We conclude that a person is declared righteous by faith!!!" Next Paul continues with a very strong ablative adverb (χωρὶς). We would express this in english by saying something like "without any sort of law-works at all!"

The arbiter/moderator is welcome to strip away this comment. But I added it initially for a reason. The question is incomplete. It's a question that betrays a lack of understanding even the basics of translation practice. For when you say that Luther added a word to the German it carries with it the unspoken assumption (accusation) that he added to the meaning of the Greek.  That is simply not the case.

Let me give you an example:  In my translation class on the Vulgate we kept running across the phrase "it was a long time until his nose became hot." We had absolutely no clue as to what that phrase meant.  It was only later, when I actually took Hebrew class that I realized that the phrase was the Hebrew idiom for taking a long time till someone "blows their top", losing all patience.  So, to translate that from the initial language (Hebrew) into the receptor language (english) you **need** to change the english wording so that you **do not** change the Hebrew content.  It is the same here with Luther's wording of this passage in Romans.  This is basic, elementary linguistic practice, not ax-grinding, agenda-ridden, doctrine-shoe-horning habit.

Also, it may surprise you to learn that Greek is not english. (-:    Greek *can* use an exclusive particle like μονον to express an "alone" thought.  But it does not *have to*.

As I mentioned, it is fine with me to strike my big long comment.  But the question is incomplete as it is written.  I don't think that the questioner meant it that way. But, nonetheless, that is how it is.  Without a basic working understanding of translation theory it is easy to conclude that Luther was adding to God's word.

Any question about James should be asked separately and not in this thread.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). I understand your wish to provide reasoning for what Luther did. Unfortunately, that's not what the question asks. However, if you want to provide an answer to the *why,* you are welcome to ask *that* question here, and then answer it yourself.

Comment: It would be nice to know what Luther actually said in his native tongue, German (in that passage you quoted).

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Apparently [the community doesn’t think it’s a different question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/37293/13677) (duplicate points to a duplicate that points to this).

Comment: Steve, I think this is on point as an answer to the question (“add” could mean two different things here, and you’ve stated that in on sense it’s obvious and gone on to address the other sense). The comments on translation philosophy are valid in their own right, but to me it seems that what’s missing is a justification of *why* you think the Greek carries the nuance of “alone".

Comment: Here's the German (at least in the Luther 1912 version):  “So halten wir nun dafür, daß der Mensch gerecht werde ohne des Gesetzes Werke, allein durch den Glauben.” (Romans 3:28 LUTH12)

Comment: I meant the German of: ""You tell me, besides, that the papists are making a tremendous fuss, because the word sola is not in Paul's text, and this addition of mine to the words of God is not to be tolerated...But because I knew—and still see with my own eyes—that none of them knows how to translate, or to speak German, I spared them and myself that trouble.." - But that's ok. Not that important.

Comment: To answer your question, Susan, Paul is setting up an exclusive statement.  "We conclude that a person is declared righteous" (λογιζόμεθα  ⸁γὰρ δικαιοῦσθαι). But then Paul front-shifts the instrumental dative for emphasis (prolepsis) out of its normal position.  So we would add weight and emphasis to this by saying something like "We conclude that a person is declared righteous *by faith*!!!"  Next Paul continues with a very strong ablative adverb (χωρὶς). We would express this in english by saying something like "without *any sort of* law-works *at all*!" (urggghh, not enough characters)

Comment: @Susan I would say that that is a serious error in identifying duplicates. *Whether* Luther did so is certainly *not* the same question as *why* he did so. And on StackExchange we are, after all, supposed to answer the actual question asked, not answer a whole different question. Most of these "answers" are really apologetics, not answers to the question asked.

Comment: What *should* be done is that answers to this question should be limited to stating whether or not Luther actually did add "alone" to his translation of Romans 3:28, which could include linguistic analysis of the meanings of the respective Greek and German words and syntax. The other question should be un-marked as a duplicate, mutually linked, and opened to answers as to *why* Luther translated it the way he did—which would require citations from historical documents for a sound answer.

Comment: Steve, [that](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8251/did-luther-add-a-word-to-romans-3/45610?noredirect=1#comment126359_45610) is information (or a line of argumentation anyway) that belongs in the answer, which you can [edit]. @Lee, IMO whether he “added” is nonsensical in terms of translation methodology without discussing *why*. Clearly all of the German words were “added” since the text was not in German. The question is whether he *inappropriately* added, which requires asking *why* and determining whether this was justified.

Comment: @Susan If that's so, then this question should be deleted altogether as a poorly worded and trivial question. FWIW, I think Luther *did* add "alone," no matter what language we're talking about, and I don't think he was justified (pun intended) in doing so. IMNSHO, it was translation driven by doctrine, bending the Bible in the direction he wanted it to go to *support* his doctrine. NT Greek is perfectly capable of saying "faith alone" if it wants to, as demonstrated by [James 2:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James+2%3A24&version=TR1550).

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Oddly enough, I pretty much agree with you (though I’d dup’ it rather than delete it).

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Why not simply edit this one rather than delete it, since all answers are assuming *why* anyway?  The other question's answer does a worse job of answering the *why* question than these do, anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

When people translate from one language to another words are sometimes added and sometimes removed (for instances, Matthew 6:1). One can compare any two Bibles and find thousands of words to argue about. Citing [Morris Protoctor](https://blog.logos.com/2012/04/logos-4-identify-english-words-added-by-bible-translators/)

> Sometimes Bible translators, for various reasons, will both insert
> extra English words and not translate all Hebrew and Greek words.

I think Catholic opposition to Luther's choice of words, and obsession with this one in particular, indicates what the Protestant reformation was all about.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a defense of what Luther did. It simply asks *whether* he did it.